# Querying Shared Drive Permissions Hierarchy with Conditons in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

My Original Data Structure Looks like this:

```
    ID  SecurityGroups_CLEAN    EDIT_Drive.1    EDIT_Drive.2    READ_Drive.1    READ_Drive.2    DENY_Drive.1    DENY_Drive.2    DENY_Drive.3    Fullname_CLEAN
    15  HighStaff               L Drive         null            null            null            null            null            null            Smith, John
    17  Foreign_National        null            null            null            null            L Drive         M Drive         Q Drive         Smith, John
    23  Domain Users            U Drive 2       null            L Drive         Q Drive         null            null            null            Smith, John
```

After some transforming, filtering, pivoting, deleting columns etc... I've managed to get it to look like this....

```
Fullname_CLEAN  Drive     Count   Permissions
Smith, John     L Drive     3     DENY_Drive.1
Smith, John     L Drive     3     EDIT_Drive.1
Smith, John     L Drive     3     READ_Drive.1
Smith, John     M Drive     1     DENY_Drive.2
Smith, John     Q Drive     2     DENY_Drive.3
Smith, John     Q Drive     2     READ_Drive.2
Smith, John     U Drive 2   1     EDIT_Drive.1
```

Basically, I need to apply the following logic to summarize a users drive level permissions.

1. If a user belongs to a security group that has Deny permissions on a drive then regardless if another user group gives them Read or Edit permissions on this same drive their permission level is Deny.
2. If a user belongs to a security group that has Edit permissions on a drive then regardless of another user group gives them Read permissions on the same drive their permission level is Edit.
3. If a user belongs to a security group that has Read permissions on a drive then their Permission level is Read.

For a Final Output of:

```
    Fullname_CLEAN  Drive       Permissions
    Smith, John     L Drive     Deny
    Smith, John     M Drive     Deny
    Smith, John     Q Drive     Deny
    Smith, John     U Drive 2   Edit
```

Now, I realize that because of my sort and pure-ABC-coincidence I could just take the "min of an aggregated column" after grouping name and drive letter because **D**eny comes before **E**dit which comes before **R**ead and this would mirror my conditions. However, I was hoping to learn the "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally for this scenario I would leave it to ABC sort as there are fixed set of inputs and they already sort as required.

If you are imagining a different scenario or different inputs, then I would Add a Custom/Calculated Column with an "if ... then ... else if ..." statement that returns numeric equivalents, e.g.

`= if [Permissions] = "Deny" then 0 else if [Permissions] = "Edit" then 1 else if [Permissions] = "Read" then 2 else 999`

Comment: Thanks @MikeHoney, see told you'd I'd catch on quick!